# Why can't this code access my JSON file in netbeans?

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to learn Javascript. I created a JSON file called "Ancest.json". Then, in a new file on netbeans I tried to execute this code accessing that file:

```
var ancestry = JSON.parse(Ancest);
console.log(ancestry.length);
```

I am getting a rejection saying "Ancest is not defined".

What am I doing wrong? Attached is a screen shot. Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: You need to assign a string ancest or var Ancest = './Ancest.json'; Depending on the location and path of Ancest.json, you may have to put in full path or linked path if the .js file exists in the same path. Also put the path in single quote or double quote. Make sure you have access to read the file. It also needs correct FS permissions.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` method accepts a string which is the JSON object to be parsed into a JavaScript object.

You need to get the content of the file or to move the content of your JSON file into a string variable in the js file. Then you can parse it:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{ "a": "test" }'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I got it to work with a simple example but not with a more complex example such : "var ances = JSON.parse([{
    "name": "Emma Million", "sex": "f", "born": "monday", "father": "Mike"},
{"name": "Frank", "sex": "m", "born": "tuesday", "father": "Paul"}]);
console.log(ances);"       Also, are you sure there is no way to enter a file name? The book I am reading uses this example: "var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE); console.log(ancestry.length);"  and it says ANCESTRY_FILE is a file. I just feel like there should be a way to enter a file because files might contain a lot of data.

Comment: you didn't pass a string to `JSON.parse` but a JavaScript array in the code above in the comment. That should be a string, sorround all with `''` and use a correct JSON

Comment: as far as i know, and as the documentation I posted you above states, that method takes a JSON object as string. If there is some trick with netbeans, then no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a string Ancest or var Ancest = './Ancest.json'; Depending on the location and path of Ancest.json, you may have to put in the full path or linked path if the .js file exists in the same path. Also put the path in single quote or double quote. Make sure you have access to read the file.

It also needs correct file system permissions. This is all contingent on who this js is running as, delegate permissions on the parent directories, etc, etc. Chances are permissions are okay for read.